# How to automatically monitor and limit resource of process on Windows

Tags: windows, resources, monitor

On Linux, normally I use `ptrace` function to trace all syscall, and kill the process if the it tries to do anything harmful to my machine, such as `system("shutdown -s -t 00")` or so.

Is there a way for me to do this on Windows?

EDIT: I want to write Sandbox program to limit time and memory usage of its child that can work on both Windows and Linux, and now it can only run on Linux via `ptrace`

Comment: This question is suitable to ask in superuser.com...

Comment: No, it is about programming. ptrace call and system() function is C function.

Comment: Am not aware of such a thing for windows...when you talk about 'limit time and memory usage of its child', that sounds like monitoring a fork'd process using the fork() call...

Comment: Kinda yah, I use fork() on Linux. Forgot that fork() on Windows is useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you attach your process to a [Job object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684161(VS.85).aspx), you can limit the CPU time and memory of the process.  That won't allow you to prevent if from performing malicious actions but it will allow you to achieve what you asked.

Comment: So combining the use of jobs and the use of privileges (see my reply) he could actually limit CPU time, memory usage and block dangerous actions.

Comment: That's what Google Chrome and Microsoft Office do in their sandboxes. Of course the challenge is actually getting it all to work (hint: It's much harder than you think) :).

Comment: I can imagine it. :) BTW, what can be done to to restrict also the filesystem usage? As far as I know ACLs here are useless, since they apply to the user, which would be the same even after restricting the privileges.
[OT]Didn't notice before that you were actually Larry Osterman; my compliments for your blog, I check it almost every day![/OT]

Comment: That's my intention anyway to create a sandbox that restricted access and limit time/memory usage. I'll try to try it though. Never really code in VS C++ anyway. Any example would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

To run an application in a sandbox you could create a new restricted access token with [CreateRestrictedToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446583%28VS.85%29.aspx) ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379306%28VS.85%29.aspx)'s some info about the privileges you can enable/disable), call [ImpersonateLoggedOnUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378612%28VS.85%29.aspx) with the new token, start the new process with CreateProcess and revert to your old token with [RevertToSelf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379317%28VS.85%29.aspx). I'm not sure if in all contexes you can instead directly use [CreateProcessAsUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429%28VS.85%29.aspx), give it a try.

Comment: Can you give me any example? I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: Wait, I re-read your question, and if you want to limit memory usage and CPU time the privileges are useless, they are to limit privileged actions (e.g. shutting down the computer).

Answer (score 0):

May be too late, just came across your post looking for the same functionality myself.

I found CPU limit 1.1

You can download it here with source code http://www.killprog.com/etce.html

I'm using it very successfully, hope it helps you